# Git Push - Correct file values during push on GitHub

Tags: git, hook, workflow

I have some sql files that we store in our repo to create some views, they can be run in different schemas and I want to make sure the files in the repo have a place holder rather than the environment name, by mistake. So for instance the file will have a single statement:
create view schema_dev or schema_stg, and in the repo is should be schema_$environment. I have a script that will go through each directory and change the files.

I started off writing a git hook for pre-push and found that works, but it changes the local files and requires the commit be done again, which if someone is still working on the file(s) the environment is reverted in their local files.

The question I have is, is this better done on a server side hook, or since I'm using github a workflow triggered by a push? I started down the workflow route and got everything working except that the changes are made in the docker container the workflow runs in but not in the actual repo. Is there a way to copy the modified repo from the work flow back to github?

basically I don't want to change the users local files but want to substitute the environment with the placeholder whenever it's copied up to the repo... What's the best practice for handling something like this?

Comment: It seems git smudge and clean filters can work. The filters can automatically update the files when check-out and check-in. And, a server side hook can prevent any ill-formatted file from a successful push, in case the client side does not format the files properly.

Comment: I checked out the clean and smudge filters and while it sounds pretty cool and useful, I'm not sure this will solve the problem, reading the documentation it seems like if a user commits a change it's going to change their local copy. So if they are iterating through their work committing changes along the way their files will be changed back. What I was hoping to find was a way to just make the change when the push is run, and not before. Maybe I misunderstood the docs, but it seems like this filter would be applied on every commit.